# using <ProtocolName> when creating protocols

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

When I create a protocol say :

```
@protocol EBSoundViewProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)playSoundPressed;
- (void)soundHintPressed;
- (void)crossOutLettersHintPressed;
- (void)fillInLettersHintPressed;
- (void)solveSoundHintPressed;

@end
```

and then I create a delegate property in my class,should it be like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate;
```

or like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<EBSoundViewProtocol> delegate;
```

because I can't really figure the differences and I didn't test but I think the first one works fine so why would i need ?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but delegate properties should usually be weak references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grady Player is correct; the bracketed bit simply indicates that the object should conform to the protocol. If you add `<EBSoundViewProtocol>`, you will get warnings for any required, but unimplemented methods of the protocol.

When declaring the protocol, you can also add non-required methods with the `@optional` keyword like so:

```
@protocol EBSoundViewProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)playSoundPressed;
- (void)soundHintPressed;

@optional

- (void)crossOutLettersHintPressed;
- (void)fillInLettersHintPressed;
- (void)solveSoundHintPressed;

@end
```

In that case, you would only have to implement the first two methods of the protocol to conform. The other three can be safely implemented or ignored.

If you leave off the `<EBSoundViewProtocol>`, you should probably wrap any calls to the delegate with a call to `-respondsToSelector:` instead to make sure the method has been implemented:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(playSoundPressed)]) {
    [self.delegate playSoundPressed];
}
```

Either way works fine.

Oh, and as René pointed out you should probably make your delegate properties weak, not strong, to avoid retain cycles.

Answer (score 2):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<EBSoundViewProtocol> delegate;
```

because that will give you a warning for:

```
obj.delegate = @"clearly doesn't adopt that protocol";
```

Comment: but it is just a compiler check, it doesn't have any bearing on the runtime, just a nice little (Duck-)Type correctness mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<EBSoundViewProtocol> delegate;
```

as this tells the compiler that delegate implements the protocol `EBSoundViewProtocol`

Comment: Either way works, although you probably want to use -respondsToSelector: before calling the delegate if you leave the protocol identifier off.